# Acción de botones generados por código

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var nproducto = [];
        var btnProducto_comprado;
        var numero_de_productos_en_inventario;
        numero_de_productos_en_inventario = 3;           
        var contador = [];
        for (nproducto = 0; nproducto <= numero_de_productos_en_inventario; nproducto++) 
        {
        $(".card-deck").append(

                   "<div class=\"card\"> <div id=\""+nproducto+"\" class=\"card-body\"> <span class=\"productos\" id=\"Producto"+nproducto+"\"> <h4 class=\"card-title\" >Producto "+nproducto+"</h4> <p class=\"card-text\"> Producto "+nproducto+" descripcion </p> <img src=\"img/"+nproducto+".jpg\" height=\"64px\" width=\"64px\"> </span> <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" id=\"btn"+nproducto+"\">Añadir al servicio</button> </div> <div class=\"card-footer\"> <small class=\"text-muted\"> Aqui el precio del producto </small> </div> </div>"
        );

        contador[nproducto] = $("#btn"+nproducto+"").click(function()                                  
            {
                alert ("pediste el producto:"+nproducto+"");           
            });
        };            
    });
</script>
```

Tengo este código que genera tantos `div`s con los productos que deseo mostrar en mi página. el asunto es que no consigo que el `alert` me indique que número de producto pedí, sin importar que botón presione siempre me indica "pediste el producto:4"

Probablemente vean horrores en el código pero ya he hecho tantas pruebas que que no se que hacer.

Apreciaría mucho su ayuda

Comment: Buenas, he intentando corregir un poco tu codigo, pero me es imposible, no estoy muy prepara para lo que tienes ahì.

Comment: Lo que te puedo decir es en los string no deberias de poner comillas dentro de comillas. Ejemplo: `"Lo que envuelve el sting con comillas dobles 'y las que pongas dentro' sean comillas simples" ` O viceversa. Otro consejo es que leas [como formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que la detalles mejor y sea mas facil ayudarte. Suerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itenta guardar la informacion del producto en el elemento y no en una variable. Esto se haria agregando un atributo que contenta la info del producto. Luego utilizas el metodo `.on` para obtener esa informacion.

En el button eliminas `id=\""+nproducto+"\"` por `data-producto=\""+nproducto+"\"`  y le agregas la clase `producto-button`:

```
<div data-producto=\""+nproducto+"\" class=\"card-body producto-button\">
  //...
</div>
```

Luego el evento clic pones fuera del for y al dar clic, buscas el atributo data-producto del elemento que le fue dado clic:

```
$(".producto-button").on("click", function(){
   alert("EL producto seleccionado fue" + $(this).data("proudcto");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, te muestra `producto 4` porque en el bucle es el último valor que asignas a la variable `nproducto`.

### Algunas correcciones a tu código:

1. Como consejo, no uses tanto HTML en el JavaScript, a menos que utilices template string (de ECMAScript 2015) o bien utilizando jQUery con HTML oculto.
2. La forma en que agregas el listener al botón de cada producto, es un poco extraña. Creo que es preferible agregar un atributo `data-id=""`a cada producto y agregar el listener fuera del bucle.
3. Declaras la variable `nproducto` como un array y luego la utilizas como índice del bucle, aunque funcione esto no es correcto.

### Ejemplo, usando jQuery y la función `.copy()` para generar un template.

```js
var products = [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "occaecat consequat dolor",
    "desc": "Nulla minim dolore anim ullamco anim. Nisi anim incididunt anim est sunt esse sint id non consectetur.\r\n",
    "img": "http://placehold.it/150x80",
    "price": "132"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "minim qui nulla",
    "desc": "Magna consectetur eu in quis. Occaecat ipsum sit labore in enim aute est.",
    "img": "http://placehold.it/150x80",
    "price": "136"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "veniam aliquip qui",
    "desc": "Reprehenderit enim amet nisi eiusmod quis. In dolore cupidatat non non aute ut sint.",
    "img": "http://placehold.it/150x80",
    "price": "82"
  }
]

var $products_container = $('.products');
var $product_template,product_id;

// ADD PRODUCTS IN CONTAINER
products.forEach(product => {
  $product_template = $('#card-template').clone(); // Copy the template

  // Template parse values
  product_id = 'product-' + product.id;
  $product_template.attr('id', product_id);
  $product_template.find('.card-title').text(product.title);
  $product_template.find('.product-img').attr('src', product.img).attr('alt', product.title);
  $product_template.find('.product-desc').text(product.desc);
  $product_template.find('.product-price').text(product.price);
  $product_template.find('.product-add-btn').attr('id', product_id);
  $product_template.find('.product-add-btn').attr('data-id', product.id);

  $products_container.append($product_template);
});

// ADD EVENT LISTENERS
$products_container.on('click', '.product-add-btn', function($event) {
  var _product_id = $(this).data('id');

  var _product = products.find(function(p) {
    return p.id == _product_id;
  });

  alert('ID: ' + _product.id + '\nTitle: ' + _product.title + '\nPrice: ' + _product.price);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- PRODUCTS CONTAINER-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="products card-group"></div>
</div>

<!-- PRODUCT TEMPLATE -->
<div id="product-template" style="display:none">
  <div class="card" id="card-template">
    <img class="card-img-top product-img" src="" alt="">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title product-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text product-desc"></p>
      <small class="text-muted product-price"></small>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary product-add-btn">ADD PRODUCT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo he utilizado un HTML oculto para representar un template. Con jQuery he creado dentro del bucle una copia de este HTML.

Para agregar el evento a cada botón de producto, he utilizado la **función `on()` de jQuery** agregando la clase del botón de producto.

Answer (score 0):

Mil gracias por su ayuda! me sirvio muchisimo sus respuestas chicos. estamos en este proyecto solo un compañero y yo y estamos bastantes nuevos en esto. Aprecio mucho esta comunidad

Saludos.